# Depth-First Search - How an finite graph can generate an infinite tree

Tags: tree, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have just started into my final year of study and I have come across a problem that I need some help with. I have looked at Depth-First Search and understand that in an infinite tree it may not find a solution due to always taking the left most path, however I do not understand how a finite graph can generate an infinite tree?

Can someone please explain or show a picture of how a finite graph can generate an infinite tree.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest graph would be with one node and one edge:

```
nodes: n
edges: (n, n)
```

You would then have an infinitely deep tree:

```
 n
 |
 n
 |
 n
 |
...
```

To avoid this you have to "tag" the nodes you have visited. A correct algorithm will have this special quality by which the tree will have exactly the same number of nodes as the isle containing the chosen root node. This is also called a [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).

On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#In_infinite_graphs) you can read:

> Every finite connected graph has a spanning tree. *(omissis)*

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as the relationship between a program (the finite graph) and the space of things it can write or read. Consider a simple recursive-descent parser. It is finite, but the streams it can parse are unlimited (including endless streams).